# 'LIKE' operator in sqlite query in FMDB

Tags: swift, sqlite, sql-like, fmdb

Please explain how I can write `LIKE` operator for code like this? I wrote code below but it seems not working on **FMDB**.

```
func getsearchStudentData(word:String) -> NSMutableArray {
sharedinstance.database!.open()
let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedinstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE name LIKE '%?' ",  withArgumentsInArray: [word])
let sarrStudentInfo : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
if (resultSet != nil) {
    while resultSet.next() {
        let studentInfo : student_info = student_info()
        studentInfo.RollNo = resultSet.stringForColumn("RollNo")
        studentInfo.Name = resultSet.stringForColumn("Name")
        studentInfo.Marks = resultSet.stringForColumn("Mark")
        sarrStudentInfo.addObject(studentInfo)
    }
}
sharedinstance.database!.close()
return sarrStudentInfo           }
```

Comment: It's "not working" is pretty vague. Please provide some details, describing what happens (r does not happen), including any error messages of logged output.

Comment: there is no error , i debug that , but query just going away, and there isn't value on studentInfo  , and closing database , it seems find nothing for giving to studentInfo (but i now some data exists with the value i searching for) , everything fine , but it seems FMDB have some changes for LIKE operator on swift language

Answer (score -2):

swift 3

try this

```
let query = "select \(field_ImageID) from \(imageTag_tableName) where \(field_ImageTag) LIKE ?;"
```

...

```
let results = try database.executeQuery(query, values: ["%\(tag)%"])
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting and explain what the code you posted does and why this solves the problem. This helps the OP and others to understand your proposed solution.